# Инкапсуляция (Коллекции, массивы)

Tags: java, коллекции, инкапсуляция

Знаю, что нужно делать так, чтобы не возвращался изменяемый объект и не терялась инкапсуляция:

```
public class CubeWarehouse{
    private Set<Cube> cubeSet = new HashSet<>;
    public Set<Cube> getWareHouse(){    
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(cubeSet);
    }
}
```

А надо ли делать так, если мы возвращаем массив:

```
public Cube[] getArray(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(cubeSet).toArray(new Cube[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет необходимости копировать Set во втором случае, т.к. `toArray(T[])` также сделает копию.

В https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T[]) сказано:

> Note that toArray(new Object[0]) is identical in function to toArray().

И в https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray():

> The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.

Comment: вы приводите доку не к тому методу, который вызывается, `toArray(T[] array)` тоже будет безопасен здесь, только вот не дает такиех гарантий )

Comment: Да, ошибся, спасибо. Но не очень понял про отсутствие гарантий. `Set` точно так же будет скопирован при вызове `toArray(new Cube[0])`. Единственное, что не будет создания нового массива, если `Set` целиком помещается в массив, переданный параметром.